# How to get javascript to reset a form?

Tags: javascript

Why is this not clearing the form contents? I tried to apply the format as I have seen in resources and every thing else works fine.

The reset button at this point does everything it should be doing except clearing the input fields. I get no errors in DevTools.

```
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return valfunc()" onreset="return resetfunc()" ;>
          <div class="container">
            <div id="usrnm">
              <label class="control-label">Username: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div id="pswrd">
              <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div id="cnfrm">
              <label class="control-label">Confirm: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm">
            </div>
            <div id="ag">
              <label class="control-label">Age: </label>
              <input class="form-control" align:"right" type="text" name="age" id="age"> <br>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onsubmit="valfunc();">
            <input type="reset" id="resetbutton" class="btn btn-default" onreset="resetfunc()">
           </div>
        </form>
```

The following is my function:

```
    <script>
        function resetfunc(){
          var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
          form.reset();
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("cnfrm").className.clear;
          document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "hidden";
          return false;
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the element with id 'output'?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error because `.className.clear;` doesn't look right at all.

Comment: Andy, sorry yes I deleted that just now as I should have earlier. Still does not work....

Comment: The element with ID output is in another section of the body

Comment: return `true` because you are currently cancelling the reset.

Comment: @AndyG Actually, the entire `return` line can just be removed.

Comment: Thank you. I did this and what Spetastium said and it worked well

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you. (I did realise that after posting ;) but wanted to convey the message firstly.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `onreset="return resetfunc()"` in the form tag and just do your cleanup (form.reset() etc.) in the onsubmit handler.

Comment: This worked! thank you. Could you explain to me what the reason for this error was?

Comment: It seems like you are listening for the onreset event on the form and are then doing the .reset(). Think about it, when the event "onreset" have triggered you are reseting the form. Reseting the form is what triggers the reset event.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few small things such as "}" and ";" in your code you need to fix to get resetfunc() to work. Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/alant/nvoztmh3/.

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return valfunc()" onreset="return resetfunc()">
          <div class="container">
            <div id="usrnm">
              <label class="control-label">Username: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div id="pswrd">
              <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div id="cnfrm">
              <label class="control-label">Confirm: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm">
            </div>
            <div id="ag">
              <label class="control-label">Age: </label>
              <input class="form-control" align:"right" type="text" name="age" id="age"> <br>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onsubmit="valfunc()">
            <input type="reset" id="resetbutton" class="btn btn-default" onreset="resetfunc()">
           </div>
        </form>

function resetfunc(){
          var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
          form.reset();
          //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
          //document.getElementById("cnfrm").className.clear;
          //document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "hidden";
          console.log("resetfunc");
          return false;
}
```

You'll see console output "resetfunc". Let me know if it clears up for you.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need JS to reset a form, just replace your reset button with this :

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: `resetfunc` does a bit more than that.

Answer (score -1):

Primarily this issue is that `return false` will cancel the `reset` event and you don't want that, so remove that line.

Also, you don't have a closing `}` at the end of your function, your function refers to an `output` element that isn't present in your HTML and `className.clear` should be `className = ""`.

Lastly, you should not be using inline HTML event attributes (`onreset`, `onclick`, etc.) in the first place. That is how event handling was done 20+ years ago and because of the fact that so many people just copy other people's HTML, the use of that technique just will not die. There are **[many reasons why you should not use this outdated technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**. Instead, you should be following modern standards and best-practices. Separate your HTML from your JavaScript completely and use `.addEventListener()` to register events.

I've updated your code to follow these modern standards.

```js
// Get all the DOM element references you'll need to use, just once:
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const cnfrm = document.getElementById("cnfrm");

// Register your event handler(s)
form.addEventListener("submit", valfunc);
form.addEventListener("reset", resetfunc);

function valfunc(){
  // Submit code here
}

function resetfunc(){
  form.reset();
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";  
  cnfrm.className = "";
  document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return valfunc()" onreset="return resetfunc()" ;>
          <div class="container">
            <div id="usrnm">
              <label class="control-label">Username: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div id="pswrd">
              <label class="control-label">Password: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div id="cnfrm">
              <label class="control-label">Confirm: </label>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm">
            </div>
            <div id="ag">
              <label class="control-label">Age: </label>
              <input class="form-control" align:"right" type="text" name="age" id="age"> <br>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="reset" id="resetbutton" class="btn btn-default">
           </div>
        </form>
        
        <div id="output">test</div>
```

Comment: Explain the down vote because this is the correct answer.

Comment: I found no difference b/w the 2, both allow the program to work EXCEPT for clearing the form. Also I did not down vote you

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think `className.clear` should be `className = ''`. You are also still referencing the full form `document.getElementById("output")`.

Comment: I will try to clean up my code like this in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @Peter You should also remove `align:"right"` (it is invalid) and use CSS instead (there is no longer an align attribute).